# Class 'gnupg' not found?

Tags: php, laravel, pgp

When i try to use gnupg class

```
$gpg = new gnupg();
```

show me this error, i used windows 8

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Windows 8. Did you include the class before instantiating it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install GnuPG?  Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php